# How to know whether Iterator of a Collection supports remove()?

Tags: java, interface, iterable, java-collections-api

All Java `Collection`s implement `Iterable`, so they must provide an `Iterator`, which specifies an optional method `remove()`. When `remove()` is called on the `Iterator`, it can throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

How do I know whether a `Collection` in the Java standard library will return an `Iterator` that supports `remove()` or not without running code?

Of course I expected this information to be in the Javadoc of the `remove()` method of the class, but instead found a bunch of links to superclasses and interfaces. For example: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#iterator-- I did not find any clarification following up on the links, either.

Comment: The only real way is to try and handle the exception, I know crappy. The Collections API is not the most elegantly design API, it should have none mutable and mutable versions of most of the core interfaces

Comment: If you read the class-level documentation for TreeSet that you link to, it implies that remove() does in fact work. Would be nice to see some example code...

Comment: Your best bet is to read the javadoc. For example `Arrays.asList` says that the returned list has a fixed size so you can imagine that its iterator can't remove. Most "standard" collections are mutable and allow removal.

Comment: Is this a genuine problem? Are you really writing code that has to deal with Iterators of multiple kinds, which may or may not support removal?

Answer (score 4):

There is no way of knowing this ex-ante. Unless it's properly documented that `remove()` is or isn't supported (and frankly, even if it **is** "properly" documented), your only way to know for sure is to try.

Comment: I'm curious about the downvote. What part of this answer is incorrect in the DV's view?

Answer (score 0):

The choice of a data structure is made on what you intend it to support so by the time you get to using it, you as a developer would already know if the underlying implementation supports removal or not.

An exception will be thrown if the actual implementation isn't in line with your assumption/ understanding.